# How do you Target urls in actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How would you add a target="_self" function onto the buttons in this actionscript (as3) I need the buttons to open within the same browser window and not a new (_blank) window:

```
skype_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("skype:mySkypeIdentifier"));
}
email_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseUpHandler);
function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:myEmailAddresss@myDomain.com?subject=rts     Esolutions enquiry"));
```

}

Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("whatever"),"_self");
```

Check the [Adobe documentation for navigateToURL](http://help.adobe.com/es_ES/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#navigateToURL%28%29) for more info.